# CSS overflow: auto for mobile browsers

Tags: css, mobile-website

I am developing a site for mobile browsers, but I am not sure if css overflow:auto works on most of them.

I couldn't find much information on the compatibility.

Much appreciated if someone could point out whether it works on some mobile browsers or not.

Comment: `overflow:auto` fails miserably in Android browsers, even on 2.3. Don't know the situation for Android 4 (ICS).

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#cats=CSS   - and there is the Mozilla standard checker too.. PS use kendo mobile, or jqeruy mobile.. that ensures that your site will be compatibly on ALL devices thanks to the hard work of the internet community.. *Get it before SOPA deletes it.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`overflow:auto should work`, because its W3C standard and supported by most of the mobile browsers

But I can't test it in various mobile devices due to lack of resources :P